# What is the difference between connectionstring and dsn?

Tags: database, datasource, connection-string

I'm having a very hard time deciphering the difference between dsn and connection string. My problem lies is that DS can give you the database name, database driver, name password . Isn't DSN able to make a connection to the database with these details. I need an explanation because this has been bugging me for a long time
 DSN has the neccessary details to establish a connection between the database and the client, doesn't it? If it does why is there a connection string?

Please answer and thanks for taking your time to answer!

Comment: I'm surpised that no one answered the question. It's a legitimate question which i'm having trouble over. The answers that i got was very vague

Comment: Well I just saw it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DSN stands for Data Source Name and it is kept in registry as a user or system value. If it is there, you can refer to connection just by its name. It looks tempting to do that way, and many old samples actually use and encourage a DSN.

However, a connection string is the connection information written as a string and doesn't need to be saved in registry. It can be built on the fly, or built and saved (probably encrypted) to a location of developer's choice (may be even another local database) - (it is in a sense developer invented DSN then). It has much more flexibility and many developers prefer it over DSN.

Comment: So DSN and connection string are meant for the same purpose; connection with the database but connection strings has more advanntages? Also "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" someone said that the "myServerAddress" is the DSN whereas the whole thing is the connection string. But doesn't the connection string consist  " Database name Directory Database driver User ID Password" _quote_ so isn't the whole thing the DSN? This is the part that makes me really confused

Comment: That "someone" is wrong. "myServerAddress" is not the DSN. Maybe "Data Source" property of a connection string is misguiding (also used as "server"). One is Data Source itself the other one (DSN) is a symbolic name referring to a whole connection to a Data Source. Connection string "generally" but not always contain Database name. It contains the driver (or provider in case of OLEDB) name. To stop confusion, you can simply think DSN are short unique "NAME"s that point to a whole connection string.

Comment: I see now, DSN is a connection to the data source like the connection but the connection string is more flexible because you can add more parameters like "Timeout" _the one i see a few times in connection string_  whereas DSN is just a connection nothing extra. Thanks a lot of curing my terrible disease! :D

Comment: Do you know if SQL Server stors its connection strings somewhere?

Comment: @MSIS, no it doesn't.